# Waiting for code to run before proceeding with program

Tags: javascript, react-native

In react native I have these two lines of code:

```
this._animateContent('contentPos', -700);
this._callOnSwipe();
```

I want to wait for the first line to finish before executing the second line. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the function

```
_animateContent: function _animateContent(state, endValue) {
    this.tweenState(state, {
      easing: _reactTweenState2.default.easingTypes.easeInOutQuad,
      duration: 400,
      endValue: -600
    });
  },
```

Comment: Does `tweenState` accept a callback parameter?

Comment: yes it does. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for react-tween-state](https://github.com/chenglou/react-tween-state):

> onEnd: the callback to trigger when the animation's done.

Put your code in an `onEnd` function.

Answer (score 0):

From this [React Tween State](https://github.com/chenglou/react-tween-state) documentation there was a configuration of `onEnd: endCallback` that you can use to run the `_callOnSwipe` function.

```
var this_parent = this;
this._animateContent('contentPos', -700 , function(){this_parent._callOnSwipe()});
_animateContent: function _animateContent(state, endValue, EndFunction) {
    this.tweenState(state, {
    easing: _reactTweenState2.default.easingTypes.easeInOutQuad,
    duration: 400,
    endValue: -600,
    onEnd: EndFunction
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need tweenState, to give you a callback or promise in the end, so that you can set the callback as this._callOnSwipe().

not sure what tweenState means, 
but I guess it would be https://github.com/chenglou/react-tween-state this one, as I just searched from Google.

And it supports onEnd attribute for callback and the example code looks like this.

`_animateContent: function _animateContent(state, endValue, callback) {
    this.tweenState(state, {
      easing: _reactTweenState2.default.easingTypes.easeInOutQuad,
      duration: 400,
      endValue: -600,
      onEnd: callback
    });
  },`

and you can then call

`var self = this;
this._animateContent('contentPos', -700, function() {
   self._callOnSwipe()
});`

Hope it helps.